# Google Jib - Is it possible to run a linux command at container startup using CMD/ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: jib, maven-jib

Is it possible to run a linux command whenever container starts from jib image using cmd or entrypoint or any other mechanism in jib maven plugin and then start the java process ?

In my case i want to run this command:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: What base image are you using?
Have you tried using a custom entry point? And including your command as a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always [set a custom entrypoint using `<container><entrypoint>`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#custom-container-entrypoint). You can start a shell script, run a different program, etc. Sometimes, you may want to use the `<extraDirectories>` feature to copy a script (and give executable permissions to it).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361658/1701388) for some ideas to run a shell script:

> Another option is to define your own `<entrypoint>` to use a shell.
> (Therefore, you need a base image that includes a shell binary (such
> as `/bin/bash`). Note that the default base image prior to Jib 3.0 was
> [Distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) and
> did not include a shell program. OTOH, [Jib 3.0+ doesn't use
> Distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/default_base_image.md).)
> In this method, you'll need to know the right Java runtime classpath
> and the main class to use in your JVM launch command. To help this,
> starting with Jib >= 3.1, Jib creates [two JVM argument
> files](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin/README.md#custom-container-entrypoint)
> inside a built image; they will hold, respectively, the classpath and
> the main class inside a built image.
>
> Knowing the entrypoint, you can write a shell script
> (`my-entrypoint.sh`):
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Assumes `java` is on PATH in the base image.
> exec java $JAVA_OPTS \
>   -cp $( cat /app/jib-classpath-file ) \
>   $( cat /app/jib-main-class-file )
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if you are on Java 9+, you can leverage the @-argument
> file:
>
> ```sh
> exec java $JAVA_OPTS -cp @/app/jib-classpath-file @/app/jib-main-class-file
> ```
>
> Place `my-entrypoint.sh` under `<project root>/src/main/jib`. This is
> the default directory for Jib's `<extraDirectories>` feature, and Jib
> will place `src/main/jib/my-entrypoint.sh` at the root directory in
> the container image. Then set the default `<entrypoint>` to this
> script:
>
> ```xml
> <container>
>   <!-- Assumes you have /bin/sh as specified at the top of /my-entrypoint.sh. -->
>   <entrypoint>/my-entrypoint.sh</entrypoint>
> </container>
> <!-- You also need to make the script executable. -->
> <extraDirectories>
>   <permissions>
>     <permission>
>       <file>/my-entrypoint.sh</file>
>       <mode>755</mode>
>     </permission>
>   </permissions>
> </extraDirectories>
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if you invoke `/bin/sh` as below, you don't have to
> configure `<extraDirectories>` to make the file executable. This may
> not look customary; you would normally make the script executable and
> run it directly. But this is perfectly valid, and there is no
> difference in terms of actual execution (as long as the shebang of
> `/entrypoint.sh` is the same `#!/bin/sh`).
>
> ```xml
> <container>
>   <entrypoint>
>     <arg>/bin/sh</arg>
>     <arg>/my-entrypoint.sh</arg>
>   </entrypoint>
> </container>
> ```
>
> It's also possible to do this without creating a script (basically
> embedding the entire script in `pom.xml` and passing it to a shell
> program). In this case, you don't need to configure
> `<extraDirectories>`.
>
> ```xml
>           <container>
>             <entrypoint>
>               <arg>/bin/sh</arg>
>               <arg>-c</arg>
>               <arg>exec java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $( cat /app/jib-classpath-file ) $( cat /app/jib-main-class-file )</arg>
>             </entrypoint>
>           </container>
> ```