# Environment variable not expanded in JVM system properties using Jib and base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, quarkus, jib

I have a Jib configuration like this:

```
environment = [
                'QUARKUS_PROFILE'         : 'test',
                'TRUSTSTORE'              : '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts/keystore.jks',
                'TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD'     : 'no.secret',
                'JAVA_APP_JAR'            : '/deployments/myapp-runner.jar',
                'JAVA_APP_NAME'           : 'myapp',
// Tried using JAVA_OPTS_APPEND or JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
                'JAVA_OPTS_APPEND'        : '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}',
                'JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS'       : '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}'
        ]
entrypoint = 'INHERIT'
```

I have a custom base image where I would like to run the official run-java.sh and be able to pass the JVM system properties expanded.

Thanks

Things I tried:

- using JAVA_OPTS_APPEND because run-java.sh makes echo of that variable and I thought it will trigger the variable expansion
- using JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS because Jib use it
- many different ENTRYPOINTS in base image and Jib configuration

  - CMD ["/deployments/entrypoint.sh"]
  - ENTRYPOINT ["/deployments/entrypoint.sh"]
  - ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/deployments/entrypoint.sh"]
  - ENTRYPOINT exec "/deployments/entrypoint.sh"
- tried the current entrypoint-ssl.sh in the base image

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-21-runtime:1.17

RUN <<EOF cat >> /deployments/entrypoint-ssl.sh
#!/bin/bash
startup() {
  echo "Running custom entrypoint for trustStore"
  exec -a "${JAVA_APP_NAME}" java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE} -cp "." -jar ${JAVA_APP_JAR} $*
}
#
startup $*
EOF
RUN chmod +x /deployments/entrypoint-ssl.sh
```

The ubi9 image has no entrypoint but

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh"]
```

[Dockerfile registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-21-runtime](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi9/openjdk-21-runtime/6501ce769a0d86945c422d5f?architecture=amd64&image=65a79bf28d0898b8f9a95f5e&container-tabs=dockerfile)

[run-java.sh](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/openjdk/blob/ubi9/modules/run/artifacts/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh#L140)

The only way I can get access to the variables is

- Option a: by accessing directly in the entrypoint command `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo ${TRUSTSTORE}"]`
- Option b: by using this entrypoint in Jib
  `entrypoint = ['/bin/sh', '-c','exec -a "${JAVA_APP_NAME}" java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE} -cp "." -jar ${JAVA_APP_JAR} $*']`

Is there any way of expanding environment variables in JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS or JAVA_OPTS_APPEND?
If not, is it possible to move the workaround entrypoint to the base image?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a Bash/shell question. Let's talk about this variable:

```
'JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS' : '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TRUSTSTORE} -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}'
```

First, you need to understand who expands (replaces) the strings of the form `$FOO` at which point in time. In your case, it's certainly not Gradle (although you could have Gradle do that easily if, for example, you know `TRUSTSTORE` is static and won't dynamically change at container runtime). Most of the time, it's a shell program that replaces such strings.

Then, it's like you are asking the shell to replace a string inside a string that is replacing yet another string. That is, you want it to replace strings recursively such that, for example, `FOO="foo $FOO"` may expand to an infinite sequence of `foo`'s.

But Bash doesn't recursively expand variables: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194028/variable-not-expanding-inside-another-variable-bash

For example,

```
$ ( INNER='inner' OUTER='$INNER' ; echo $OUTER )
$INNER
```

OTOH, the following script expands `$INNER` first and then assigns the expanded value (the string literal of `inner`) to `OUTER`.

```
$ ( INNER='inner' OUTER="$INNER" ; echo $OUTER )
inner
```

---

Lastly, I am not sure if this will help, but just in case: [Jib - How to use environmental variables from base image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59357410/1701388)