# Runtime environment variable in jib args?

Tags: jib

How do I make it so that Kubernetes replaces `\$(ENV)` with the runtime value of the `ENV` environment variable when the container is started?

```
//build.gradle.kts
jib {
  from.image = "prom/prometheus"
  to {
    image = "${dockerRepository}/${project.name}:${project.version}"
  }
  container {
    ports = listOf("8080")
    environment = mapOf(
      "FOO" to "BAR"
    )
    entrypoint = listOf("INHERIT")
    args = listOf(
      "--enable-feature=agent",
      "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/\$(ENV)/prometheus.yml",
      "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
      "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles",
      "--web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:8080",
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: First, you need to understand and figure out who can/should replace the string of the form `\$(FOO)` at which point in time: Gradle at build time, or a shell program like Bash or Kubernetes at runtime? Unfortunately, I don't really know anything about Kubernetes, but to me, it'd be pretty unusual if Kubernetes had a feature to read container arguments to expand strings before using them as new container arguments. But to be sure, I'd ask a general Kubernetes question without mentioning Jib. Alternatively, you can always have Bash expand strings.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361658/1701388 might be helpful.